# Allowing IE to load scripts from localhost

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, express

I'm currently running a site on port 443 locally which is an ASP.NET web application.

Through a query string I'm able to provide a CDN URL for a plugin that is used in the ASP.NET web application.

This works for IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but IE is not even attempting to send a request for the JavaScript file.

The JavaScript file is hosted on an Express server and is just injected into an ASPX file similarly to this:

```
<script src="<%= CDN_URL_FROM_QUERY_STRING %>/myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>
```

I'm assuming it's some Internet Options setting within IE 11 that I have to change but I am not sure of which one.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can start by fixing the ASP tag `<% CDN_URL_FROM_QUERY_STRIGN &>` should be `<%=CDN_URL_FROM_QUERY_STRIGN %>`

Comment: That's not actually how it's listed in the site. It works for other browsers, if it was truly incorrect the other browsers wouldn't work. I wrote that one as an example.

Comment: I have edited my example code to reduce confusion.